# Mandrill/Email - Build Encrypted Email Preferences Link

Tags: email, encryption, preferences, mandrill

I am using Mandrill + Mailchimp to send out e-mails and I am trying to build an update e-mail preferences link that goes to my site and they can manage their preferences from there.

Right now I'm building the links in the template like:

```
<a href="http://dev.chatterplot.com:9000/email/update?e_email=*|EMAIL|*">
```

The user clicks the link and the server knows which email to update, but there's nothing stopping a user from plugging in a different email in the query parameter.

I'm wondering if there's a way to encrypt emails in the template and decrypt them via Mailchimp, but I'm wondering how to build a link that passes a hash that I can decrypt on the server because as of right now there's no way to check if the referrer is mandrill via Headers.

How do other companies go about this?